# Setting up HTTPS on Deno , with self signed certificate?

Tags: deno

I was setting up a Deno server to handle HTTPS request, I used self signed certificates to do the job.
Used below code for this:

```
import { serveTLS } from "https://deno.land/std/http/server.ts";

const body = new TextEncoder().encode("Hello HTTPS");
const options = {
  hostname: "localhost",
  port: 443,
  certFile: "./path/to/localhost.crt",
  keyFile: "./path/to/localhost.key",
};
// Top-level await supported
for await (const req of serveTLS(options)) {
  req.respond({ body });
}
```

I ran this code as: `deno --allow-net --allow-read app.ts`
I get following error:

```
ERROR RS - rustls::session:571 - TLS alert received: Message {
    typ: Alert,
    version: TLSv1_3,
    payload: Alert(
        AlertMessagePayload {
            level: Fatal,
            description: BadCertificate,
        },
    ),
}
error: Uncaught InvalidData: received fatal alert: BadCertificate
► $deno$/errors.ts:57:13
    at InvalidData ($deno$/errors.ts:135:5)
    at constructError ($deno$/errors.ts:57:13)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/dispatch_json.ts:41:12)
    at sendAsync ($deno$/dispatch_json.ts:96:10)
```

Is it possible to use self signed certificates with Deno ?
What went wrong and how to fix it ?

Comment: Alternative way to fix the problem (from upstream rustls issue): https://github.com/ctz/rustls/issues/124#issuecomment-337983154

Comment: @KevinQian yeah this one looks related, I will have look at it and update.

Comment: Can't even get to the point where I could your error, copied your code, set it up with my local self signed cert (works with my node server). Getting error:
`Uncaught PermissionDenied: Permission denied (os error 13)
    at unwrapResponse ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:43:11)
    at Object.sendSync ($deno$/ops/dispatch_json.ts:72:10)
    at Object.listenTls ($deno$/ops/tls.ts:67:10)
    at listenTls ($deno$/tls.ts:51:22)
    at serveTLS (server.ts:313:20)` 

originating from rust, couldn't figure out a solution based on what's written here: https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6757

Comment: @exside it was a problem with my certificate files, strangly the same certificates were working with nodejs. I created local cert than using this [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert), then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

It was a problem with my certificate files, strangly the same certificates were working with nodejs. 
I created local certificates and key than using this [mkcert](https://github.com/FiloSottile/mkcert), then it worked!

Comment: Inetersting! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 2):

If you're on MacOS, the best way to fix this is to instruct Deno to look at the system as the CA store.

Run this, then try again to see if you still get a warning/error:

`export DENO_TLS_CA_STORE=system`

You probably also want this in your `.bash_profile` as well.